# how to use Wildcard search in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs, filter, wildcard

I want to implement a wildcard search. Write now what i am doing is :

```
var patt = new RegExp(input); 
if(patt.test(searchString))
    $scope.filteredModel.push(searchString);
```

But this does not give wildcard search result. i.e If I enter `v*`, I should get all strings *starting* with `v` . But in this case , as I am using a `regExp`, I am getting all strings (as `v*` means *0 or more* occurrences of `v`) . How can I customize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take the user input and transform it to this wildcard equivalent. `*` should become `.*` and you should add `^` at the beginning to match only things starting with the given pattern:

```
var patt = new RegExp('^' + input.replace(/\*/g, '.*'));
```

Now you can test with `patt` and get the desired result.

Also you might want to escape the other special characters in regex:

```
var specialCharacters = /([.\\+?[^\]$(){}=!<>|:-])/g;
var patt = new RegExp('^' + input.replace(specialCharacters, "\\$1").replace(/\*/g, '.*'));
```

This might look scary, but all it does is add `\` in front any of these: `. \ + ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`. This way if a user enters `v*ABC+` it will try to match something that starts with `v` and ends with `ABC+`, rather than end with `ABC` and variable number of `C`s like `ABCCCCCCC`.

Comment: one more question .. how to replace all occurrences of * by .*

Comment: I edited the answer. Adding a `\g`(global) to a regular expression does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

If you are useing regular expressions maybe you could try useing the short hand versions for different characters.

> Some implementations of regular expressions allow you to use shorthand versions for commonly used sequences, they are:
>
> \d, a digit ([0-9])
>
> \D, a non-digit ([^0-9])
>
> \w, a word (alphanumeric) ([a-zA-Z0-9])
>
> \W, a non-word ([^a-zA-Z0-9])
>
> \s, a whitespace ([ \t\n\r\f])
>
> \S, a non-whitespace ([^ \t\n\r\f])

[Source](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/Regex.html)